# Chrome browser new date("2014-03-18T10:52:42.55") thanged the time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
new Date("2014-03-18T10:52:42.55");    
result:     
Tue Mar 18 2014 06:52:42 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

My time : 10:52:42.55

Result time: 06:52:42 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

How to get the result in GMT000?

I have to show date and time separately.

Comment: highly recommend you get moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) to handle all your js date needs

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you want- to set the date at GMT timezone, suffix the string with a 'Z':

```
new Date("2014-03-18T10:52:42.55Z");
/* Tue Mar 18 2014 06: 52: 42 GMT-0400(Eastern Daylight Time)
 */
```

If you want to return a string to display UTC time use

```
new Date("2014-03-18T10:52:42.55Z").toUTCString()
```

and parse the return,

or use the Date object methods like D.toUTCDate(), D.toUTCHours()